# How to repeat a composed html header on each page printed

Tags: html

I have the scenario below in html5:

```
<article>
  <header style="position: fixed;">
    <section style="float: left;">
      <img src="path_to_img" />
      <h3>My report</h3>
    </section>
    <section style="float: left;">
      <ul>
        <li style="width: 50%; text-aligment: right;">Customer Name:</li>
        <li style="text-aligment: left;">XYZ company</li>
        <li style="width: 50%; text-aligment: right;">Segment:</li>
        <li style="text-aligment: left;">Electric equipment</li>
      </ul>
  </header>
  <main id="content">
     ... html content ...
  </main>
</article>
```

So, I'd like to print this "report" with the header above repeating on each page but, when  the content is filled, I don't know why, sometimes I have the header on the first page only, sometimes it appears from the second page ahead and I can't figure out the error.

Any tip is welcome...

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you're using a server-side language.  If so, which?  If so, what does that code look like?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I'm using PHP to get data from database, process and return a JSON to the page. Also, I'll use angularJS to parse all data to that "... html content ..." area. Please, take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVBJL). Anyway, I'd like to have the header printed on each page but, I'm getting the weird behavior I mentioned. Tks.